# Count if SUM returned no rows in MS Access

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am looking for a way to do a count if a sum statement returns 0 rows or value.

I have a SQL statement in Access that sums all the values of DiskGB based on my criteria.  My problem is, when there is nothing to show, it shows a blank field, and it needs to show a 0.  Here is what I have:

```
SELECT Sum([DiskGB]) AS SumDisk
FROM TCRS
WHERE (((Site)="1" Or (Site)="2" Or (Site)="3") AND 
       ((Tier)="Silver") AND 
       ((Business) Like "CC*")
      );
```

I have look on too many places and I cannot find a way to get this resolved, can you guys help?

Comment: Looks like you need to show 0 for the sum. Why do you need a count?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show 0 when your sum is `NULL`, you can try this:

```
SELECT IIF(isnull(Sum([DiskGB])), 0, Sum([DiskGB]))  AS SumDisk
FROM TCRS
WHERE (((Site)="1" Or (Site)="2" Or (Site)="3") AND 
   ((Tier)="Silver") AND 
   ((Business) Like "CC*")
  );
```